# MDX query just on dimension contents

Tags: mdx

Is it possible to write a MDX query that just queries and returns data on a dimension?

For example, assume that I have a 'Sales' cube that has a 'Customer' dimension, and the customer dimension has three properties:  'Customer Name', 'Customer ID' and 'Customer Business Sector'.  I want a query that returns the 'Customer Name' and 'Customer ID' properties for all those customers that have a 'Customer Business Sector' value of 'Banking'.

Comment: you mention "three properties"  ... but are you actually meaning three hierarchies within the Customer dimension?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [calculated members](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/calculated_members.php), something like:

```
with 
   member xName as dim.currentMember.NAME
   member XProp as dim.currentMember.properties('prop')

select 
  { [xName], [xProp] } on 0, 
  dim.allMembers       on 1

from [cube]
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

```
SELECT
NonEmpty
    (
      Customer.CustomerID.CustomerID.MEMBERS * Customer.CustomerName.CustomerName.MEMBERS, 
      (Customer.[Customer Business Sector].&[Banking], Mesures.SomeMeasure)
    )
            ON 1,
{} ON 0
FROM [Sales]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about "properties" then maybe the following pattern:

```
WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[CustName] AS
        [Customer].CURRENTMEMBER.properties('Customer Name')
   MEMBER [Measures].[CustID] AS
        [Customer].CURRENTMEMBER.properties('Customer ID')
   MEMBER [Measures].[CustSector] AS
        [Customer].CURRENTMEMBER.properties('Customer Business Sector')
   SET [CustBankers] AS
       FILTER(
          [Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS AS C
         ,[Measures].[CustSector] = 'Banking'
       ) 
SELECT
  { 
    [Measures].[CustName]
   ,[Measures].[CustID] 
  } ON 0, 
  [CustBankers]  ON 1
FROM [YourCube];
```

I suspect then when you mention "property" you're referring to three attribute hierarchies within the Customer dimension. If this is the case then something more like the following:

```
WITH
   MEMBER [Measures].[CustName] AS
        [Customer].[Customer Name].CURRENTMEMBER.member_caption
   MEMBER [Measures].[CustID] AS
        [Customer].[Customer ID].CURRENTMEMBER.member_caption
   MEMBER [Measures].[CustSector] AS
        [Customer].CURRENTMEMBER.properties('Customer Business Sector')
   SET [CustBankers] AS
       EXISTS(
          [Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS
         ,[Customer].[Customer Business Sector].[Banking]
       ) 
SELECT
  { 
    [Measures].[CustName]
   ,[Measures].[CustID] 
  } ON 0, 
  [CustBankers]  ON 1
FROM [YourCube];
```